# how to extend the expire time in a normal access token

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have been reading about JWT and i am trying to implement it in my server.  I already have a API that receive an user and send back a JWT with an expire time. Well... then i have other method that verify the token.
Is there any method that i can use to expand the expiration time of a normal Access token?  i read that there is other type of token called Refresh Token... but it is more than i need... i just want increase the expire time, thats all

```
 jwt.sign({ user }, SECRET , { expiresIn: '5m'} ); // HOW I CREATE THE TOKEN
 jwt.verify(req.token, SECRET , (error, data) => {} <---- // HERE IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO INCREASE
```

Comment: I think it's constraint that you have to change token with new expire and the client should store new token for next request

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the expiry time in a JTW is set when the JWT is generated and signed. You cannot change an existing token, e.g. by changing the expiry time, because after the change, the signature would not be correct anymore. Being able to make such changes would invalidate the security that JWT utilizes.

I suggest you read up on how the JWT works. Check out the `Signature` part of the following article: [Introduction to Json Web Tokens - jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

What can you do about it? Just issue a new JWT.

Comment: No. Just issue a new token, just as you would for a new user. In the new token, you can set a new expiration time.

Comment: okey, but it seems a bit mmm heavy for the server if you have lot of users it has to generate a looootttt of them... definetly i think, it would be nice to have a method that can expand the expiration time... thank for all!

Comment: That solely depends on the amount of users and the default expiration time of the tokens, but normally the JWT should not be a concern in terms of server load. Also, if you consider and of the answers here as helpful, consider giving them an upvote. :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to recreate the token again. Token is signed which makes it unique. It defeats the purpose of the token if you change the expiry time and magically becomes valid.

Can I try to understand what is stopping you from generating a new token at the place where you want to increase the exp time?

Comment: wow, i didn't expect that, after i receive the token in my client, i use this token in every petition that the client does to the server and the server verify if this token is correct... so.. instead to generate a new token in every petition, i think that it would be nice if i just can expand the expiration time... but as you say... that is not possible.

Comment: idea here is you generate a new token where you want to increase the expiration time.. server will anyways verify the token next time it is sent back..